# Fixing FM8 to a given pitch OR filter MIDI notes and transpose to a given value

Tags: synthesizer, reaper

I'd like to make some percussive sounds with FM8, which I really love.
I couldn't find where can I "fix" the pitch to a given value - in other synths I can switch off the "key follow" and set it to a pitch, say, C-1.

To reason behind that is I'd like to beef up the kick drum of drum VSTs with synth kick, so I route the drum MIDI to the FM8 track (no, I don't want to write and maintain a separate track for that!).

So...

1. Is it possible to fix the pitch of **FM8**, so any MIDI note would produce the same sound? ***OR***
2. Can I filter the MIDI values (in **REAPER**) of the kick of the rum VST track and transpose it to a certain note? (E.g. My kick is on C-5, so I filter out everything that is not C-5 and then automatically transpose it to my kick)

Therefore, I could totally control the root note of my kick, which would be really nice and handy.

Answer (score 1):

In FM8 set your operator ratio to zero and then specify a fixed offset frequency of the required frequency.  If in doubt look in the manual how to do this.

You can probably do your MIDI filter in Reaper, but it is not software I use so I can't be sure.

Comment: I need to know the exact frequency of the note, right? For example, for a really low A, it's easy, it's 55 Hz. But I need to do the math for each note, right?

Comment: Yes, but a Google search (Frequency of Musical Notes) will save you having to calculate it yourself.